# Riverpod: why use a Provider instead of a global final variable

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I came across some code using Riverpod, for example for retrieving http data with Dio, using a Riverpod provider as below:

```
final client = Provider((ref) => Dio());
```

then use it to fetch data:

```
final response = await ref.watch(client).getUri<Map<String, Object?>>(uri, cancelToken: cancelToken);
```

Why use a Riverpod Provider for the client as it reference will never change and not use a global variable instead?:

```
final clientDio = Dio();

final response = await clientDio.getUri<Map<String, Object?>>(uri, cancelToken: cancelToken);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a provider allows replacing the implementation with a different one using overrides.

For an HTTP client, this can allow replacing it with a fake one that returns pre-determined responses.
This can be useful for testing or development/debugging purposes.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But if I use a `var`  instead of a `final` for the client, I can I can assign the fake one to, no ?

Comment: Ok I think I have understand it, when using a Provider I can `watch` to it for a change using overrides with a fake one and got the widget tree rebuilded what does not happen with the `var` instance ?